# Uniqueness of the solution of $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Given a matrix equation
$$ {A}_{n\times m} x_{m\times 1}=b_{n\times 1},$$

how to find out if the solution vector x is unique?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an important result called Rouchè-Capelli Theorem:
$$Ax=b \ \ \text{admits solution(s)} \iff \text{rank}(A|b)=\text{rank}(A)$$
Now if this condition is verified then:
$$Ax=b \ \ \text{admits an unique solution} \iff  \text{rank}(A)=m$$
So withouth any premise:
$$Ax=b \ \ \text{admits an unique solution} \iff  \text{rank}(A|b)=\text{rank}(A)=m$$

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $A$ that you get is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. For the solution if it exists, is unique if the null space of the matrix is trivial. That means that rank($A$)$=m$. But for all this to make sense $m\leq n$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $b$, solution exists IFF   $C(A)=\mathbb{R}^n$   IFF   $rankA=n$

I suppose you found such $b$, then

$b$ is unique IFF $N(A)=\{0\}$ IFF number of free variable is zero.